# Manage shared library for different version of Ubuntu

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

We build a shared library which depends on `libsdl-gfx`.

On Ubuntu  12.04 through 14.10, `libSDL_gfx.so.13` is linked; On Ubuntu **15.04** and **15.10**  `libSDL_gfx` is updated to `libSDL_gfx.so.15`.

In order to make it work, we need to build another version of our shared library which depends on `libSDL_gfx.so.15`.

So the question is what is the correct way for this case? Is it possible to just build my library once which can be used on both **Ubuntu 12** and **Ubuntu 15**? Thanks.

LJ

Answer (score 0):

> So the question is what is the correct way for this case?

What you are already doing: build two versions of your library.

> Is it possible to just build my library once which can be used on both Ubuntu 12 and Ubuntu 15?

No. Assuming `libSDL_gfx.so` developers are competent, there is a *reason* they changed the external version of the library: an ABI change. If you tried to use your library with ABI-incompatible version of `libSDL_gfx`, you would get a crash (or worse -- subtle memory corruption). Read about external library versioning [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/819-0690/chapter5-5/index.html).